# retrieving multiple rows with different ids in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to write a query in mysql, where my table structure is given below

```
place_id    state_id    city_id     place_name  
    1           0           0           United States   
    2           1           0           Alabama     
    3           0           2           Auburn  
    32          0           0           Canada  
    33          32          0           Alberta     
    34          0           33          Calgary
```

here i have united states id which is 1, using this id i want to retrieve all the states in united states and the cities of each state.
Here,

1. if state_id and city_id is 0 then it is a country
2. if city_id is 0 then it is a state
3. if state_id is 0 then it is a city
4. place id is auto_increment

please some one help me, thank you.

Comment: Post your expected output.

Comment: I don't envy you your data model. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For United States  you could use a self join for joining the same table 3 times.

```
select t1.place_name, t2.place_name, t3.
from my_table t1 
inner join my_table t2 on  t1.place_id = t2.state_id 
inner join my_table t3 on t3place_id =   t3.city_id
where t1.place_name  ='United States';
```

Comment: thank you for replying self joining solved my problem